# quantum geographic information system

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, qgis

```
def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""
        # show the dialog
        self.dlg.show()
        # Run the dialog event loop
        x = self.dlg.lineEdit.text()
        y = self.dlg.lineEdit_2.text()
        z = int(x)+int(y)
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
        # See if OK was pressed
            # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
            # substitute with your code.
        QMessageBox.information(self.iface.mainWindow(),"sum is =", "%d" %z)
```

But it shows an ValueError in `z=int(x)+int(y)`.x and y are from line edit box..type of x and y is unicode...
How should I add x and y?

Comment: Please post the error message.

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: What is the type of `x` and `y`? You can find this by doing `print type(x)` and print `type(y)`. Also print the values in x and y.

Comment: type of x and y is  unicode
and x and y are from the users which will be entered in lineedit

Comment: If the input is definitely a number, then please try `int(float(x))`.

Comment: If that doesn't work, moving your question to http://gis.stackexchange.com/ would increase the chances of getting the solution.

Comment: Replace z = int(x)+int(y) with z = float(x)+float(y)

Answer (score 0):

def run(self):

```
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""
    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()
    self.dlg.spinBox.clear()
    self.dlg.spinBox_2.clear()

    # Run the dialog event loop


    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    if result:
        x = self.dlg.spinBox.value()
        y = self.dlg.spinBox_2.value()
        z = x+y
    # See if OK was pressed
        # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
        # substitute with your code.
        QMessageBox.information(self.iface.mainWindow(),"sum is =","%d" %z)
```